# For loop over contacts list is not executing

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to create a contact management program.My plan is to use an arraylist of a class called contact that I have created. After storing the details,I can get the name and number using the get method.The below code is the main code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.printf("1.Manage contacts \n2.Message \n3.Quit \nSelect an option: ");
            Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList<Contact> contacts=new ArrayList<Contact>();
            int choice=inp.nextInt();
            int counter = 0,i;
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.printf("\n1.Show all contacts \n2.Add a new contact \n3.Search for a contact \n4.Delete a contact \n5.Go back to the previous item \nSelect an option: ");
                    Scanner inpt=new Scanner(System.in);
                    int opt=inpt.nextInt();
                    if (opt==2) {
                        System.out.printf("Enter the name: ");
                        Scanner nm=new Scanner(System.in);
                        String name=nm.next();
                        System.out.printf("Enter the number: ");
                        Scanner numb=new Scanner(System.in);
                        int num=numb.nextInt();
                        Contact c=new Contact(name,num);
                        counter++;
                        System.out.printf("Counter: %d\n",counter);
                        contacts.add(c);
                    }
                    else if (opt==1){
                        i=0;
                        for (i=0;i<counter;i++){
                            //System.out.printf("Inside\n"); This line is to check if the loop is running 
                            //or not
                            contacts.get(i).showname();
                            contacts.get(i).shownum();
                        }
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code for contact is below.It has the two methods shownum and showname which should help me display the name and number.

```
package com.example.attemp1;

public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private int number;
    public Contact(String name,int number){
        this.name=name;
        this.number=number;
    }
    public void showname(){
        System.out.printf("Name: %s\t",this.name);
    }
    public void shownum(){
        System.out.printf("Number: %d\n",this.number);
    }

}
```

But the problem is that for loop to show the name and number doesn't work.I mean that the loop isn't even executing.

Comment: I don't see a for loop in your code. Please show us how you want to use a for loop.\

Comment: Why do you keep a `counter` variable at all? You can just iterate with `for (int i = 0; i < contacs.size(); i++)` or even `for (Contact c : contacts)`.

Comment: Yes @daniu i did that earlier it worked,but when I used counter it didn't work man.

Comment: The for loop is in the else if part @NomadMaker

Comment: Why do you have an i++ at the end of the for loop? The loop already increments i with an i++ statement. If you want to increment i by two, you should use an i += 2 inside the for statement.

Comment: Yeah sorry man,was trying to see the error,forgot to remove the second i++.But now I have removed it.

Comment: Don't use `counter`. You have `contacts.size()` for that. You can also do `for (Contacts c : contacts)`. You also only need a single Scanner, not one for each input

Comment: If `number` is supposed to be a _phone number_, it should be a `String`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re-initialise your Contacts List and Counter at each iteration of the main loop.
You should move the initialisations before the while(true).

I.E.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     // MOVE INITIALISATION HERE
     ArrayList<Contact> contacts=new ArrayList<Contact>();
     int counter = 0,i;
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.printf("1.Manage contacts \n2.Message \n3.Quit \nSelect an option: ");
            Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
            //REMOVE INIT FROM HERE
            //ArrayList<Contact> contacts=new ArrayList<Contact>();
            int choice=inp.nextInt();
            //REMOVE INIT FROM HERE
            //int counter = 0,i;
```

However a less error prone mode is to change the for loop too with

```
 for( Contact c:contacts)
```

so you don't have to mantain the `counter` variable and you can remove it completely

Comment: Was stuck at this.Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: Uh how to do that dude?

Comment: You have to press the check under the votes section and it will became green

Answer (score 2):

Your arraylist initialization is misplaced, so you are creating a new arraylist every time you receive a new command and any changes would be deleted.

To solve this, place `ArrayList<Contact> contacts=new ArrayList<Contact>();` before the while loop.

You also use a counter variable which you should place outside the loop for the same reason, however note that the ArrayList class has a method called `size()` that you can use to keep track of the number of items, so you don't need it.

You do not need to create a new scanner object every time you want to scan something, you can create it once outside the while loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You do not need to create a variable named `i` at the start of your method (function in c) like the c language, this is the common way to use for loops in java:

```
                for (int i=0;i<counter;i++){
                    //System.out.printf("Inside\n"); This line is to check if the loop is running
                    //or not
                    contacts.get(i).showname();
                    contacts.get(i).shownum();
                }
```

Comment: not enough, you should move the counter variable too

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code and your variables `contacts`, `counter` and `i` is placed inside the while loop which reset in each iteration. you should define those variables above your while loop like below:

```
public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0,i;
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts=new ArrayList<Contact>();
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.printf("1.Manage contacts \n2.Message \n3.Quit \nSelect an option: ");
            Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);

            int choice=inp.nextInt();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.printf("\n1.Show all contacts \n2.Add a new contact \n3.Search for a contact \n4.Delete a contact \n5.Go back to the previous item \nSelect an option: ");
                    Scanner inpt=new Scanner(System.in);
                    int opt=inpt.nextInt();
                    if (opt==2) {
                        System.out.printf("Enter the name: ");
                        Scanner nm=new Scanner(System.in);
                        String name=nm.next();
                        System.out.printf("Enter the number: ");
                        Scanner numb=new Scanner(System.in);
                        int num=numb.nextInt();
                        Contact c=new Contact(name,num);
                        counter++;
                        System.out.printf("Counter: %d\n",counter);
                        contacts.add(c);
                    }
                    else if (opt==1){
                        i=0;
                        for (i=0;i<counter;i++){
                            //System.out.printf("Inside\n"); This line is to check if the loop is running 
                            //or not
                            contacts.get(i).showname();
                            contacts.get(i).shownum();
                        }
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it already it works. Cheers